# For which $n,p$ does $2n^2-n=2^p-1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For which $n,p$ does $2n^2-n=2^p-1$, where $n,p$ are positive integers. The solutions that I have found: $n=1,p=1$ and $n=3,p=4$. Are there any other? If no, how do I prove that that are not any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=4n-1$. Then the given equation translates to:

$x^2+7=2^{p+3}$, which asks for solutions of the form $4k-1$ to the [Ramanujan-Nagell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan-Nagell_equation).

The solution to this might have been discussed elsewhere on this site.